# Accessing all records in a field

Tags: ms-access, vba

Just started using VBA and I'm trying to access all the data in a dummy table I set up called `Employees`.

This is the code im trying:

```
Sub getRecords()

Dim dbs As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees"
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)

End Sub
```

The ultimate aim here is to print the contents to the screen — would this involve breaking down the record set into different components? If so what components could make up a typical record set?

The table format is as follows:

```
Emp_Id    - Number
Emp_Name  - Text
Emp_Email - Text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through the fields:

```
Sub getRecords()

Dim dbs As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees"
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)

Do while not rst.eof
   For each fld in rst.Fields
      Debug.Print fld, fld.name
   Next
   rst.MoveNext

   ''You can also edit or add
   rst.Edit
   rst!Emp_Name = "Something"
   rst.UpDate
Loop

End Sub
```

I would avoid calling variables names that are also properties, such as SQL.

For updates, you are usually best to use an Action query and Execute againt a database object:

```
 db.Execute "UPDATE aTable SET aField = 'Some text'", dbFailOnError
```

Comment: nice answer - some things though: Coming from a java background you can seperate lines of text using \n is there a similar option in VBA?

Comment: You can use vbCrLf, vbCr and vbLf, also chr(13) and chr(10) separately or together, and vbNewLine. Debug.Print prints single lines to the immediate window (ctrl+G for the window). Always remember MS Access is a lot easier than you think :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start by looping through the records.  Try:

```
Do While Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF
...
Loop
```

To do that. BOF and EOF relate to the beginning and end of the recordset respectively.  If there's no data in the table then the whole loop will be skipped.

From there you can look at the fields individually by either using an index to relate to the position of the field in the select list, or by referring to the field name, like so:

```
Do While Not rst.EOF And Not rst.BOF
    Debug.Print rst.Fields("myfield")
    Debug.Print rst.Fields(0)
Loop
```

That's a starting point.  Intelisense should really help you with this.

PS: always remember to close your `recordset` objects afterward to reclaim the memory:
    rst.Close()
    Set rst = Nothing

Kind regards,
Paul.

Comment: Forgot to add the MoveNext though! Ooops!

Comment: Was gonna say but that line doesn't work - I get run time error 91. Where does the MoveNext object go?

Comment: You may want to consider what type of recordset you actually need.  For your example you would be best going for a forward only type - much faster, especially as you don't appear to want to edit the info.  Remou has shown the way for editing.

Comment: Put rst.MoveNext inside the loop.  Always worth checking for the BOF, too.

Comment: "Always worth checking for the BOF" Not with DAO unless you are moving backways. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243790(v=office.12).aspx Closing the recordset is not essential these days, either, but I guess it does not hurt.

Comment: Regarding type, it is best to accept the default. This is DAO, not ADO.

Comment: I disagree with accepting the default.  You should tailor your record access to the requirements of the application at the time: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240785%28v=VS.60%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240785%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

Comment: "Not with DAO unless you are moving backways" - Not true. If there are no records in the recordset the loop is passed over in the example I gave.

Comment: "Closing the recordset is not essential these days, either, but I guess it does not hurt" - actually it can do, especially if you are doing a lot of processing.  If you don't close of the recordset it remains open.  Disposing of the recordset then leaves an open object in memory which is not disposed of properly until the application is closed.  If you have a lot of things to do there is the potential to run out of resources. [http://www.tutcity.com/access/vba-traps-working-with-recordsets.4012.html](http://www.tutcity.com/access/vba-traps-working-with-recordsets.4012.html)